# Can someone help me with my code? (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ethan/Documents/Coding/test2.py", line 3, in <module>
    buy = input("Marijuana plants cost 200$ ea, opium seeds cost 300$")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'm' is not defined
```

I bet it will be obvious but, I'm new to python and need some help.

code:

```
balance = 2500
FinalPrice = 0
buy = input("Marijuana plants cost 200$ ea, opium seeds cost 300$")     
while (buy != "o") and (buy != "m"):
    buy = input("That's not on the market! type 'm' if you want to buy Marijuana and 'o' if you want opium!")
if buy =="o":
    o = input("How many opium seeds? Press c to cancel")
    if o=="0":
        o = input("invalid number, input again")
    elif o =="c":
       input("You cancelled the trade. Type in a command to do something else")
    oprice = (o*300)
    print(oprice)
    FinalPrice-=FinalPrice
    FinalPrice+=oprice
    obuy = input("This is the final price, press b to buy or c to cancel")
    if obuy =="c":
        input("You cancelled the trade. Type in a command to do something else")
    elif obuy =="b":
        if oprice > balance:
            print("Not enough money! Sell more drugs to earn more money.")
        elif oprice < balance:
            print("you bought", o , "Opium seeds for", oprice , "$")
    input("What do you want to do next?")    
elif buy =="m":
    m = input("How many Marijuana plants? Press c to cancel")
    if m=="0":
        m = input("invalid number, input again")
    elif m =="c":
        input("You cancelled the trade. Type in a command to do something else")
    mprice = (m*200)
    print(mprice)
    FinalPrice-=FinalPrice
    FinalPrice+=mprice
    mbuy = input("This is the final price, press b to buy or c to cancel")
    if mbuy =="c":
        input("You cancelled the trade. Type in a command to do something else")
    elif mbuy =="b":
        if mprice > balance:
            print("Not enough money! Sell more drugs to earn more money.")
        elif mprice < balance:
            print("you bought", m , "Marijuana plants for", mprice , "$")
input("What do you want to do next?")
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
I got the m to work, but then I implemented o and it didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using python2?

Comment: oh. yes I am. I thought I was using 3. if I switch over will it work?

Comment: Careful.  `input()` on Python3 returns your input as a string, whereas `input()` on Python2 tries to evaluate that string.  Use `raw_input()` on Python2.

Comment: It would likely work in python3. Of course, you could just switch `input` to `raw_input` in your current code, and have it work in python2

Comment: I changed them all to "raw_input"

Comment: Marijuana plants cost 200$ ea, opium seeds cost 300$m
How many Marijuana plants? Press c to cancel2
22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ethan/Documents/Coding/test2.py", line 34, in <module>
    FinalPrice+=mprice
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: I don't want it to loop 2 :O

Comment: @inspectorG4dget okay, I got rid of the mprice-=final price stuff, but how do I stop it from looping the number I input?

Comment: Cast your `str`s into `int`s. `int('2')*2` is `4`. `'2'*2` is `'22'`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget so do you mean        mprice = int('200')*m? It didn't work. I still got the loop

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I'm sorry I'm new to python. How do I multiply a variable by a number?

Comment: I'm out at dinner right now. I'll try to get to this when I get back home

Comment: I mean `200*int(m)`. Try that

Answer (score 0):

This code is supposed to work on python 3.

If you are using python 2, then wherever you want your input to be of integer type, use

int(raw_input())

to accept the input. 
Whenever you want it to be a string, simply use

raw_input()